# Calculate overlap time in seconds for groups in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, range, overlap

I have a bunch of timestamps grouped by ID and type in the sample data shown below.

I would like to find overlapped time between start_time and end_time columns in seconds for each group of ID and between each lead and follower combinations. I would like to show the overlap time only for the first record of each group which will always be the "lead" type.

For example, for the ID 1, the follower's start and end times in row 3 overlap with the lead's in row 1 for 193 seconds (from 09:00:00 to 09:03:13). the follower's times in row 3 also overlap with the lead's in row 2 for 133 seconds (09:01:00 to 2020-05-07 09:03:13). That's a total of 326 seconds (193+133)

I used the partition clause to rank rows by ID and type and order them by start_time as a start.

How do I get the overlap column?

```
row# ID type      start_time             end_time               rank. overlap
1    1  lead      2020-05-07 09:00:00    2020-05-07 09:03:34       1  326
2    1  lead      2020-05-07 09:01:00    2020-05-07 09:03:13       2  
3    1  follower  2020-05-07 08:59:00    2020-05-07 09:03:13       1
4    2  lead      2020-05-07 11:23:00    2020-05-07 11:33:00       1  540
4    2  follower  2020-05-07 11:27:00    2020-05-07 11:32:00       1
5    3  lead      2020-05-07 14:45:00    2020-05-07 15:00:00       1  305
6    3  follower  2020-05-07 14:44:00    2020-05-07 14:44:45       1    
7    3  follower  2020-05-07 14:50:00    2020-05-07 14:55:05       2
```

Comment: please define what do you mean by `overlapped`. Please illustrate with example and calculation

Comment: Hi @Squirrel. I added an example and edited the original question. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: `the follower's start and end times in row 3 overlap with the lead's in row 1` Why you are not considering `row 3` overlap with `row 2` ? Is there any significant in `lead` and `follower` ?

Comment: I am. There is an overlap of 133 seconds between row 3 and row 2. I have considered that in the total overlap for ID 1. 193 seconds between row 1 and row + the 133 seconds = 326 secs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this a couple of way and got it to work.

I first joined 2 tables with individual records for each type, 'lead' and 'follower' and created a case statement to calculate max start time for each lead and follower start time combination and min end time for each lead and follower end time combination. Stored this in a temp table.

```
CASE
    WHEN lead_table.start_time > follower_table.start_time THEN lead_table.start_time
    WHEN lead_table.start_time < follower_table.start_time THEN patient_table.start_time_local
    ELSE 0
END as overlap_start_time,
CASE
    WHEN follower_table.end_time < lead_table.end_time THEN follower_table.end_time
    WHEN follower_table.end_time > lead_table.end_time THEN  lead_table.end_time
    ELSE 0
END as overlap_end_time
```

Then created an outer query to lookup the temp table just created to find the difference between start time and end time for each lead and follower combination in seconds

```
select temp_table.id,
       temp_table.overlap_start_time,
       temp_table.overlap_end_time,
       DATEDIFF_BIG(second,
            temp_table.overlap_start_time,
            temp_table.overlap_end_time) as overlap_time FROM temp_table
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the times completely cover the total duration.  If this is always true, you can use the following logic:

```
select id,
       (sum(datediff(second, start_time, end_time) -
        datediff(second, min(start_time), max(end_time)
       ) as overlap
from t
group by id;
```

To add this as an additional column, then either use window functions or `join` in the result from the above query.

If the overall time has gaps, then the problem is quite a bit more complicated.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question and set up a db fiddle for the problem.

Comment: Hi Gordon. I added an example and edited the original question. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: @adityatandel . . . Is there an issue with this answer?  If so, set up a db<>fiddle to illustrate the issue.